# Storing a name or word in matrix on Jupyter

Tags: python, matrix, jupyter, jupyterhub

I would like to know how to store a word or a name in a matrix. For instance, if I create a matrix of 3's, I have the code:

```
x = np.empty(shape=(100,5))
for  i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,5):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        c = a+b
        x[i,j]=c
print(x)
```

But, let's say, I'd like to write the word mango in a matrix:

```
x = np.empty(shape=(100,5))
for  i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,5):
        x[i,j]= "mango"
print(x)
```

I get this output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7512/2833526917.py in <module>
      3 for  i in range(0,100):
      4     for j in range(0,5):
----> 5         x[i,j]= "mango"
      6 print(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'mango'
```

I'd appreciate any help on this. Than you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'matrix'?  You created a 2d shaped numeric array.  Why are you using `numpy`?  Why not a Python list, or list of lists?  Where's the `numpy` tag?

Answer (score 0):

The default `dtype` to `empty` is `float`, so you'd need to specify `dtype=object` to create the initial empty matrix that you can store string values in.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.empty(shape=(100,5), dtype=object)

for  i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,5):
        x[i,j]= "mango"
print(x)
```

Comment: As a sidenote, there is no need to fill the array by iterating over its elements. `x = np.full((100, 5), "mango")` will produce the same result.

Comment: @bb1 This is the example that the OP came up with. I assume they're going to fill the array from some other source.

Comment: Sure, my  comment was meant for the OP in case it fits their usage case.